# How to install mod_pagespeed in docker apache httpd

Tags: apache, docker, pagespeed, mod-pagespeed, apache-modules

I have a docker based apache httpd server. I need to install `mod_pagespeed` into that.

The flavour I am using is debian based not alpine based for now - for some reasons.

Following is the list of commands required to install the module in debian/ubuntu dist - from the official site

```
wget https://dl-ssl.google.com/dl/linux/direct/mod-pagespeed-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i mod-pagespeed-*.deb
sudo apt-get -f install
```

This is giving error

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mod-pagespeed-stable:
 mod-pagespeed-stable depends on apache2; however:
  Package apache2 is not installed.
```

This is obvious because there is no `apache2` service installed, only `httpd` command works.

Even the folder structure is different then regular debian/ubuntu installation.

I don't find any `.so` file anywhere, otherwise I can put it in some directory and do a `LoadModule`.

I guess I need to do a custom build from source, is there any easy way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following `Dockerfile` as a base:

```
FROM debian:stretch

ENV APACHE_RUN_USER www-data
ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP www-data
ENV APACHE_PID_FILE /var/run/apache2/apache2.pid
ENV APACHE_RUN_DIR /var/run/apache2
ENV APACHE_LOCK_DIR /var/lock/apache2
ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/log/apache2
ENV LANG C

RUN apt-get update \
    && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y apache2 wget \
    && wget https://dl-ssl.google.com/dl/linux/direct/mod-pagespeed-stable_current_amd64.deb -O /tmp/modpagespeed.deb \
    && dpkg -i /tmp/modpagespeed.deb

RUN mkdir -p /var/log/apache2 /var/run/apache2 /var/lock/apache2 \
    && chown www-data:www-data /var/log/apache2 /var/run/apache2 /var/lock/apache2

CMD ["apache2", "-DFOREGROUND"]

EXPOSE 80
```

Build the image and launch a container, you'll get a response header similar to `X-Mod-Pagespeed: 1.13.35.2-0`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Mostly @Michael's answer is correct, however for those who uses default docker's apache module (like me) following answer would suffice.

Because debian's apache installation is different than docker apache's installation. (And if you already have setup/customised all the configuration and cannot re-customise to be debian's structure)

I have built the pagespeed module from that answer and then copied the module to my installation.

Dockerfile

```
FROM debian:stretch as pagespeed

ENV APACHE_RUN_USER www-data
ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP www-data
ENV APACHE_PID_FILE /var/run/apache2/apache2.pid
ENV APACHE_RUN_DIR /var/run/apache2
ENV APACHE_LOCK_DIR /var/lock/apache2
ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/log/apache2
ENV LANG C

RUN apt-get update \
    && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y apache2 wget \
    && wget https://dl-ssl.google.com/dl/linux/direct/mod-pagespeed-stable_current_amd64.deb -O /tmp/modpagespeed.deb \
    && dpkg -i /tmp/modpagespeed.deb

FROM httpd:2.4.43

# all these things are my custom configuration. You probably don't need these
COPY --chown=root:www-data ./docker-assets/httpd-custom.conf $HTTPD_PREFIX/conf/httpd.conf
COPY --chown=root:www-data ./docker-assets/httpd-default.conf $HTTPD_PREFIX/conf/extra/httpd-default.conf
COPY --chown=root:www-data ./docker-assets/httpd-vhosts-custom.conf $HTTPD_PREFIX/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
COPY --chown=root:www-data ./docker-assets/httpd-ssl.conf $HTTPD_PREFIX/conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
COPY --chown=root:www-data ./docker-assets/httpd-mpm.conf $HTTPD_PREFIX/conf/extra/httpd-mpm.conf

# pagespeed module adding as custom build here. You may need to change some paths in .load file
COPY --chown=root:www-data ./docker-assets/pagespeed.load $HTTPD_PREFIX/conf/extra/
COPY --chown=root:www-data ./docker-assets/pagespeed.conf $HTTPD_PREFIX/conf/extra/
COPY --chown=root:www-data ./docker-assets/pagespeed_libraries.conf $HTTPD_PREFIX/conf/extra/
# Or directly copy from build stage
# COPY --from=pagespeed --chown=root:www-data /etc/apache2/mods-available/pagespeed.conf $HTTPD_PREFIX/conf/extra/
# COPY --from=pagespeed --chown=root:www-data /etc/apache2/conf-available/pagespeed_libraries.conf $HTTPD_PREFIX/conf/extra/
COPY --from=pagespeed --chown=root:www-data /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_pagespeed.so $HTTPD_PREFIX/modules/
COPY --from=pagespeed --chown=root:www-data /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_pagespeed_ap24.so $HTTPD_PREFIX/modules/
# pagespeed end
```